# how to update cart when same product is added more than once in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Cannot update item quantity when a product is added more that once in the cart the params pass are user id and product id
I am creating a cart when first product is added in cart and pushing unique products. But when same product is added for the second time i want to update the products qunatity x 2 instead of adding the entire record

here is my code:

```
router.get('/add-to-cart/:userID/:id', function (req, res, next) {
    var productId = req.params.id;
    var userId = req.params.userID;
    Cart.findOne({ user: userId }, (err, doc) => {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    if (doc == null) 
    { 
        var cart = new Cart;
        Product.findById(productId, (err, product) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        let item={
            id:product._id,
            name:product.name,
            price:product.price,
            subtotal:product.price*1,
            qty:1
        }
        cart.items.push(item);
        cart.user = userId; // set cart user
        cart.totalPrice = item.price * item.qty;
        cart.totalQty ++;
        cart.save((err, data) => {
            if (err)  res.send(err);
                    res.json(cart);
            });
        });
    }

    else{
        Product.findById(productId, (err, product) =>{
        let item={
            id: product._id,
            name: product.name,
            price:product.price,
            subtotal:product.price*1,
            qty:1
        }
        doc.items.push(item);
        doc.save(err,data=>{
            res.json(doc);
        })
        doc.totalQty ++;
        doc.totalPrice += item.price*item.qty;


    })
    }
})
});
```

module.exports = router;

here is my cart schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var schema = mongoose.Schema;
// sample user schema
var CartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    product: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'Product'},
    totalQty:{type: Number,default: 0},
    totalPrice: {type: Number,default: 0},
    items : Array,
    user:{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: 'User'}
});
module.exports =  mongoose.model('Cart', CartSchema);
```

Comment: put your schema as well...

Comment: yes updated the schema

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by finding the cart item information from database. if it exist you can use the quantity to update the cart information.

If It isn't exist simply create a new cart item in database.

**For Example.**

**Controller Class**

```
const cartService = require('../services/cart-service');

class CartController {

    createCart = async (req, res, next) => {
        let cart;
        const cartItem = await cartService.findCart({ userId: req.user.id, productId: req.body.id });   //Your Condition to find cart item.
        if (!cartItem)
            cart = await cartService.createCart(req.body);
        else
            cart = await cartService.updateCart({ productId: req.body.id, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1, userId: req.user.id });
        if (!cart)
            return res.status(422).json({ success: false, message: 'Failed To Add Into Cart' });
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Item Added Into Cart' });
    }


}

module.exports = new CartController();
```

**CartService**

```
const CartModel = require('../models/cart-model');

class CartService {

    createCart = async data => await CartModel.create(data);

    updateCart = async (filter, data) => await CartModel.updateOne(filter, data);

}

module.exports = new CartService();
```